# Custom font is not loaded in stripe element

Tags: stripe-payments

I am specifing custom font for stripe element according to [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create#stripe_elements-options). But stripe input font is differs with other input(same custom font).

I have created simple page with two inputs. First is html `<input>`, second is stripe elements input. I am specifing custom font for html input and for stripe input. But stripe input font is different(stripe input is second):

[image: first - common input, second stripe input]

Here is js code to create stripe element:

```
var elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [
        {
            cssSrc: 'http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e?family=GT+Walsheim+Pro+Regular',
        },
    ],
});
var elementStyles = {
    base: {
        fontFamily: 'GT Walsheim Pro Regular',
        fontSize: '25px',
    },
};
var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    style: elementStyles,
});
cardNumber.mount('#example-card-number');
```

Full reproduce code is available at [github repo](https://github.com/muzuro/stripe-elmements-gtwalsheimfontissue). Do you have any ideas why input font looks different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom fonts in Stripe have to be loaded over HTTPS. Neither the font-face definition file nor the underlying custom font files are being served securely:

```
http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e?family=GT+Walsheim+Pro+Regular
```

```
@font-face {font-family: "GT Walsheim Pro Regular";
    src: url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.eot"); /* IE9*/
    src: url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.woff2") format("woff2"), /* chrome firefox */
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.woff") format("woff"), /* chrome firefox */
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.ttf") format("truetype"), /* chrome firefox opera Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
    url("http://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.svg#GT Walsheim Pro Regular") format("svg"); /* iOS 4.1- */
}
```

The fix is to serve both the font-face file and an underlying font resources using HTTPs. As a quick example to see it working you can take one of the `woff` files and provide it to Stripe as follows:

```
  var elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [
      {
        family: "GT Walsheim Pro Regular",
        src:
          "url(https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/0abeb2471faeb5269db428b9eac2075e.woff)",
        weight: "500",
      },
    ],
  });
```

Note that I updated the protocol from one of the resources to `https://`.

With this change, the fonts load correctly in the iframe as seen below:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it works over https! Do you know if it will work with relative url? I mean if site schema will be https

Comment: Yes it should! Per: https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/css_font_source_object#css_font_source_object-cssSrc